# querying elasticsearch multi-field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following settings configured for an 'asset_test' index in elasticsearch:

```
{
  "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
      "analyzer" : {
        "str_filtered_search_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase"]
        },
        "str_prefix_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase", "prefix"]
        },
        "str_substring_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase", "substring"]
        },
        "path_analyzer" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "path_hierarchy"
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "prefix" : {
          "type" : "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram" : 2,
          "max_gram" : 24,
          "side": "front"
        },
        "substring" : {
          "type" : "nGram",
          "min_gram" : 2,
          "max_gram" : 24
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "asset" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_id": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "_rev": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "type": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "requiredBySystem": {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "heading" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "text" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "users" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "categories" : {
              "type" : "multi_field",
              "fields" : {
                "categories" : {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "index" : "not_analyzed"
                },
                "path" : {
                  "type" : "string",
                  "analyzer" : "path_analyzer"
                }
              }
            },
            "choices" : {
              "properties" : {
                "text" : {
                  "type" : "string"
                },
                "checked" : {
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            "requiredBySystem": {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "required": {
              "type" : "boolean"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I have this document in the index:

```
{
   "_id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca0181620418d4",
   "_rev": "14-173e71c77d32f0360f7afb2206b2a334",
   "type": "entryForm",
   "requiredBySystem": true,
   "formName": "Basic",
   "attributes": [
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203d609",
           "type": "text",
           "heading": "Brand",
           "text": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203dc61",
           "type": "text",
           "heading": "Model",
           "text": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203decd",
           "type": "text",
           "heading": "Location",
           "text": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203e68e",
           "type": "userSelectMenu",
           "heading": "Assigned To",
           "users": [
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203e9c9",
           "type": "categories",
           "heading": "Categories",
           "categories": [
               "/Airport/Hangar 1",
               "/Airport/Hangar 2"
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203ebdd",
           "type": "text",
           "heading": "Owner ID",
           "text": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203f0da",
           "type": "textarea",
           "heading": "Description",
           "text": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816207uy5a",
           "type": "radio",
           "heading": "Radio Buttons",
           "choices": [
               {
                   "text": "Button 1",
                   "checked": false
               },
               {
                   "text": "Button 2",
                   "checked": true
               }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816205tgh6",
           "type": "checkboxes",
           "heading": "Checkboxes",
           "choices": [
               {
                   "text": "Box 1",
                   "checked": false
               },
               {
                   "text": "Box 2",
                   "checked": true
               }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca0181620k81gt",
           "type": "select",
           "heading": "Select Menu",
           "choices": [
               {
                   "text": "Option 1",
                   "checked": false
               },
               {
                   "text": "Option 2",
                   "checked": true
               }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to find the document with the following query but it is not being found:

```
{
    "query": {
        "field": {
            "attributes.categories.path": "/Airport"
        }
    }
}
```

Kinda stuck on how to make this work.

*** Update: I made 'attributes' a nested type and querying with the following query now appears to work:

```
{
  "query" : {
      "nested" : { 
        "path" : "attributes",
        "query" : {
          "term" : {
            "attributes.categories.path" : "/Airport/Hangar 1"  
          } 
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Your nested query looks good.  The reason your Field query (probably) didn't work is because it uses query_string, which performs a preprocessing step.  "/Airport" is preprocessed into "Airport", and that token doesn't exist in the index so it doesn't match.  Checkout the [Inquisitor](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) plugin to help play around with queries, its great for debugging these problems.

Comment: @Troy, it'd be good if you turned your update into an answer. I'd do it for you but you should get the credit for it.

Comment: I changed my update into an answer...thanks Noel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Update: I made 'attributes' a nested type and querying with the following query now appears to work:

```
{
  "query" : {
      "nested" : { 
        "path" : "attributes",
        "query" : {
          "term" : {
            "attributes.categories.path" : "/Airport/Hangar 1"  
          } 
        }
      }
  }
}
```